# AWS IAM Creating group of admins that can create users with no admin right in their group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am pretty new to AWS IAM and what I am trying to achieve is a group of "sub-admins" that can create their own user's with less privilege, ideally those users and its respective admin wouldn't see any other group or admin.

so I would like to have something like this:

```
groupLeaders--> adminA --> user1GroupA
                       --> user2GroupA

            --> adminB --> user1GroupB
                       --> user2GroupB

            --> adminC --> user1GroupC
```

So if possible that admin[A-C] cannot cannot see each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into AWS Organization, splitting admin A B and C into three distinct organizational unit.

For example "HR Department" , "Developers" and "Account Department".

You, the Organization root, will have access to the individual units' billing etc.

However this is not the only way. You can also use federation to import a list of users (for example active directory) or even social login like Facebook or Google. However this will require some setting up. You basically define 3 Roles A, B and C and allow different group of people to sign in and assume different roles.

Bare in mind that creating individual IAM user is not recommended and should be kept at a minimum. For the following reasons:

- More users require more maintenance
- Users may change department or leave the organization
- Any access granted to an individual user will not be kept up-to-date by AWS
- When new AWS services are released you will need to modify the users manually